# Cannot find -lagent when compiling c source code (incompatible library)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ubuntu, compiler-errors

With gcc in ubuntu I used this command to compile my source code:

```
gcc 1.c -L. -lagent -lm -lpthread -o 1
```

but I got this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ./libagent.so when searching for -lagent
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lagent
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Install the library `libagent`.

Comment: `gcc -shared` or create `libagent.a`?

Comment: thx and how to install libagent?

Answer (score 1):

The linker is telling you that the file `./libagent.so` exists, but **isn't in the appropriate format**.

It could be an empty file, or built for 32-bit instead of 64-bit, or it could be a symlink pointing to the wrong version.

Comment: thanks for your reply,afer reading your post i know the problem,but i still dont know how to solve it. can you help me thank you best wishes

Comment: You need to run `file libagent.so 1.o`.  Chances are, one is 32-bit and the other 64-bit.  You either need to change the compilation options so that `1.o` is created with the same mode as the library (`-m32` or `-m64`; guess which does which!), or you need to recompile the library with the same mode as your program.  Use the same `-mNN` option for compilation and linking.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your command line parameters first.

`gcc 1.c -L. -lagent -lm -lpthread -o 1`

You call the compiler `gcc` with the input source code of `1.c` and then you specify an additional (link) library path to include the current directory (`.`) `-L.`. Then you tell it to link against the agent and pthread libraries, where shared (dynamic) libraries have the default name format of libNAME.so where NAME is replaced with the name. Static libraries have the default file extension `.a` (from the term *archive*). Then you specify the output (executable in this case) to be the file `1` (digit one, not the letter 'ell').

`/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ./libagent.so when searching for -lagent`

This is the linker (`ld`) telling you that the file ./libagent.so (it found presumably in the current directory) is not a valid shared library format as it was expecting. This could be for a different machine architecture (x86-64, ARMle, PowerPC, MIPS) or a incompatible library format (I don't know if library files, .so, have any `COFF` or `ELF` or `PE` dependencies or not). Or simply otherwise empty or corrupted (e.g. interrupted output due to errors compiling / linking).

So you normally want to **not** include your current directory in your linker's search path, *unless* you have the copy of the library that you have not yet installed (typically to /usr/lib/ or /usr/local/lib/), such as you wrote the library and wish to link test programs to it before you install it.

Debian and Unbuntu-oriented part of the answer:

Normally you want to install shared library's runtime component (often named something like `libagent`) and the associated development files (most often at least a header file and hopefully a manpage) in the format `libagent-dev`. RPM based Linux systems use `libagent-devel` style naming conventions (from memory).  So `sudo aptitude install libagent-dev` should do the trick if that is the package's name.